# .split() by character when string has same character side-by-side

Tags: javascript

Check the following examples and their outcome:

```
'222'.split('') // ["2", "2", "2"]
'222'.split('2') // ["", "", "", ""]
'2a22a'.split('2') // ["", "a", "", "a"]
```

Why is the last example not `["", "a", "", "", "a"]` ?

Comment: Why do you think that *should* be the result? Where do you see two empty strings each surrounded by `2`?

Comment: @Barmar `'22'.split('2')` results in `[ "", "", "" ]`, that is maybe why. Intuition? (maybe wrong intuition, but intuition nevertheless)

Comment: That's the empty string before the first `2`, the empty string between them, and the empty string after the last `2`.

Comment: Your expected result would occur if you had `2a222a`.

Answer (score 18):

Because it splits like this

```
'2a22a'.split('2') becomes    "" (2) "a" (2) "" (2) "a"
```

where the "a" on each side of the 22 will be one array item each, but between the 22, there will be only one "".

---

So if one add "a" both at the beginning and between the 22, it will be more clear.

```
'a2a2a2a'.split('2') becomes  ["a", "a", "a", "a"]
```

---

You could also say; every split character, here `2`, will become a comma `,` in the array definition.

Comment: It is like a css-margin. If there's already one empty place, the next split wont add another empty value for the array. CSS-Margins wont add up if you have two boxes next to each other with a margin of 5px each, the margin between them will also just be 5px and not ten. Is this comparison right?

Comment: @evayly You could say that....or every split char, here "2", will become a comma `,` in the array definition.

Comment: I think your comment is more visual and would actually add to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will make it more visual and easy acceptable so no need of extra explanations:

```
'|a||a|'.split('|')
'|a|a|a|'.split('|')
```

result:

```
[ "", "a", "", "a", "" ]
[ "", "a", "a", "a", "" ]
```

If you have some doubts about some functionality, make a easy acceptable by your brain example. In this case close to the nature of the split method.

Answer (score 0):

split() converts a string to array using the character(s) passed as parameter as separator.

like @LGSon says all between this charater(s) will be an element of the array.

is clearer if you split with slash '/' instead of '2':

`'a/b/c/d'.split('/')` -> `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

`'a//b'.split('/')` -> `["a", "", "b"]`

`'/a//a'.split('/')` -> `["", "a", "", "a"]`